# {"Incorrect syntax near 'C'."}.....Error Debug

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, insert

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=ILLUMINATI;" + 
    "Database=DB;Integrated Security= true");
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(
    "Insert into FileUpload ('FilePath','TypeId','UploadedBy','UploadedDate') 
    values (" + savePath + "," + typeid + "," + NAME + "," + DateTime.Now+ ")", conn);

conn.Open();
comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

It's giving an error saying:

> {"Incorrect syntax near 'C'."}

Can anybody tell me the error please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to put single  `''` quotes around the value strings not around the column names

try this

```
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(
    "Insert into FileUpload (FilePath,TypeId,UploadedBy,UploadedDate) 
    values ('" + savePath + "','" + typeid + "','" + NAME + "',"
```

assuming `typeID` is string, if not dont put `''` around it

Comment: @ILLUMINATI7590: Note that this code is still vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You *really* should be using parameterized queries.

Answer (score 5):

The reason it's giving the error is as Haris says - you're putting the single quotes in the wrong place.

However, it would be a *very bad idea* to "fix" this by just putting the quotes in different places. Instead, you should use a parameterized query:

```
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand
    ("Insert into FileUpload (FilePath, TypeId, UploadedBy, UploadedDate)" +
     " values (@savePath, @typeid, @name, @now)", conn);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@savePath", savePath);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@typeid", typeid);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", NAME);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@now", DateTime.Now);
```

By expressing your data *as data* instead of as part of the "code" (the SQL) you avoid having to worry about conversions (e.g. date formats) *and* you avoid SQL injection attacks.

See the [`SqlCommand.Parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) documentation for more details (or search for "parameterized queries").

Comment: Using parameters.AddWithValue in SqlCommand is block the SQL injection attacks? I can't clearyle understand..

Comment: @Soner: Not just AddWithValue - basically expressing all data as parameters (however you populate them) instead of within the SQL is the best approach to avoiding SQL injection attacks. It avoids the data (which may well be from the user) from being treated as SQL.

Comment: Nice to know. But for clear understand, can you give an example for this situation. For example, in question's code, how can user get SQL Injection? As i understand, we should use *Parameters* value when we insert, delete etc. processing right?

Comment: @Soner: Imagine if the user typed a savePath which included a quote, brackets etc. They could basically provide their own parameters for the rest of the data, corrupting the original intention. Simply put, you should use parameters for *all* non-hardcoded data in SQL queries. (I'd personally use them for hard-coded data as well in many cases, for consistency... especially where dates are involved, as they can cause a pain for conversions.)

Answer (score 1):

Enclose the columns, who has varchar and datetime type,in a single quote.

```
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(
    "Insert into FileUpload ('FilePath','TypeId','UploadedBy','UploadedDate') 
    values ('" + savePath + "'," + typeid + ",'" + NAME + "','" + DateTime.Now+ "')", 
    conn);
```